# MIP SDK Java Wrapper: How to retrieve label's protection settings like encrypt & mark properties of the label

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

Need help to retrieve label's protection attributes like **"encrypt files & email"** and **"mark the content of files"** programmatically using MIP SDK Java Wrapper library.

There were no fields in Label class to hold these values:

```
public class Label {
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String color;
private int sensitivity;
private String tooltip;
private String autotooltip;
private ActionSource actionsource;
private Label parent;
private List<Label> children;
private List<Pair<String, String>> customSettings;
private List<String> contentFormats;
private boolean isActive;
}
```

**Label Attributes:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The label object doesn't contain this information. Labels are used to resolve a set of actions that must be taken to label something. If you want to understand which protection and marking actions to take, you'd need to implement the Policy SDK, call ComputeActions(), then iterate through the collection of actions that are returned to properly label the document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-handler-policy-computeactions-cpp

https://github.com/azure-samples/mipsdk-dotnet-policy-quickstart/tree/main/